# Using Ant, Fail if does not start with a particlar string without ant-contrib

Tags: ant

I am new to Ant scripting and my version is 1.6.5 on SUSe Linux 11,  Can you please help in achieving below

```
       <fileset dir="${target.location}" includes  = "${file.list}"/>
```

Here the target.location is a directory that is passed as an Input from a property file by the  user. Now I need to write a validation to make sure that the directory location should always start with /properties.

The user can pass anything like /properties/***/*** , but the starting string should always be "/properties" or else throw the error to the user and exit,  I cannot use ant-contrib because for adding any libraries to the existing ant should go through a lot of approval process.

Comment: You can use antcontrib tasks without having to add anything to the Ant installation, you just provide the appropriate classpath to the `taskdef`. You're making life very hard if you don't allow yourself _any_ third party libraries and you're stuck on 1.6 without `scriptcondition` or `matches`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to implement a custom script condition check. Support for Javascript comes from the JVM so doesn't require additional jars:

```
<project name="demo" default="check">

  <property name="target.location" value="/properties/some/path"/>

  <condition property="found.prefix">
    <scriptcondition language="javascript">
      self.setValue(String(project.getProperty("target.location")).indexOf("/properties")==0)
    </scriptcondition>
  </condition>

  <target name="check">
    <fail message="target.location must be prefixed with '/properties'" unless="found.prefix"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but scriptcondition doesn't exist in ant 1.6.

Comment: @IanRoberts ANT 1.6.5 is over 8 years old. Upgrading might be an option.

Comment: I definitely understand your suggestion about the old ANT version, but the issue is the ANT we are using comes part of the application server product binary and we do not have any separate libraries for ANT ,So to upgrade that ANT I believe I have to add the libraries in that application server product installation binary which is a difficult approval process.

Comment: I was able to achieve this with the help of shell scripting exec task, thank you all